# Use Django password widget and change password form in user admin site

Tags: python, django, hash, django-admin, django-users

I am extending the user model in Django and have create a PIN number field that is hashing into the database correctly.

However, in the Django admin when viewing a user the pin number field is populated with the hash. Is it possible to use the Django password widget:
[image]

so that the PIN number field is not populated:

[image]

and therefore by extension use the template for the change password form to also change the pin?

Comment: Note that the password is *masked*: it does not show the full content, it shows asterisks for most of the data.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem how do you mask the text in the admin-site?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why you couldn't use the form. Here's the Django User form: [`django.contrib.auth.forms.UserChangeForm`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/3c05ab295df0b89192182c5c5309aaaff5cb4bb0/django/contrib/auth/forms.py#L141) that's used in the admin. The form field you want is [`django.contrib.auth.forms.ReadOnlyPasswordHashField`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/3c05ab295df0b89192182c5c5309aaaff5cb4bb0/django/contrib/auth/forms.py#L53)

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I have managed to get the password hash field showing. Just have to create the 'change pin' form. I will post the code when complete. Fairly new to Django but enjoying it.