# Redirect to user change form in Django Admin

Tags: python, django, django-admin, django-urls

I have almost completed adding a PIN number field for users in the Django admin.

[previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59790374/use-django-password-widget-and-change-password-form-in-user-admin-site/59790628#59790628)

I have a separate form to change the PIN number, very similar to that seen when changing a password. I have an issue with the successful redirect after a form submit. I would like to redirect back to the user change form, but have been able to do so.

What is the url pattern required to redirect to that page on a successful redirect? When submitting a new password successfully you can redirect back to the user change page therefore it is possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The admin urls follow a pattern `admin:<app>_<model>_<action>`, so if you had a model named `Foo` in an app named `bar` you would access the change admin URL with the following reverse

```
reverse('admin:bar_foo_change', kwargs={'object_id': object.pk})
```